# Does Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) work without TLS?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Below I have tried to justify my question, "Does Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) work without TLS? I believe I am missing understanding part of the spec and was hoping for some direction. I also have a second question, Does PKCE only relate to using Cookies to store the auth token (not mentioned in spec)?

Please help me identify the misinformation or lack of information in my comments below.

[rfc7636](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#page-3)'s introduction section describes an attack authorization code interception attack on public clients. It states,

> the attacker intercepts the authorization code returned from the
> authorization endpoint within a communication path not protected by
> Transport Layer Security (TLS) ...

The Introductions PreCondition section item 4 indicates that TLS not protecting the response .

The Introductions "To mitigate this attack" paragraph the states

> This works as the mitigation since the attacker would not know this
> one-time key, since it is sent over TLS and cannot be intercepted.

and

> this extension utilizes a dynamically created cryptographically random
> key called "code verifier".

[RFC6949](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749) mentions attacks around the use of cookies; however, rfc7636 does not specify pertaining only to cookies or local storage of the Auth token. Therefore is seems it would resolve an attack on the request if the auth token was also stored dynamically. Is this the case?

Comment: I wrote an article on how PKCE is implemented in .NET Core if you're interested:
https://davidklempfner.medium.com/how-pkce-works-6e21e46a2274?sk=03e69a07af01f1a613407948da92e1aa

Answer (score 1):

PKCE is used as a proof that the party which initiated authentication (via a browser redirect) is the same party completing it (via an HTTP POST).

It works without TLS, as in steps 4 and 8 of my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/basicspa-oauthworkflow/), where the code verifier in step 8 must match the code challenge in step 4.

Cookies are not directly related to PKCE. However, in a browser based app without PKCE or a client secret, malicious browser code only needs to send the authorization code to get tokens. If tokens are stored in cookies then the malicious code can only perform session hijacking.

PKCE was originally introduced for public clients that cannot use a client secret. These days, it is recommended for [all clients that use the code flow](https://oauth.net/2.1/), including those with a client secret. And of course TLS should also be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gary:
You stated: "It works without TLS, as in steps 4 and 8 of my blog post, where the code verifier in step 8 must match the code challenge in step 4."

But if the transport layer was using TLS, wouldn't the token be protected and the Hack be prevented?

You said, "If tokens are stored in cookies then the malicious code can only perform session hijacking."

But if the PKSE was stored outside the code but inside data protected by TLS (stay the auth header), wouldn't it also be protected?

Comment: TLS provides data confidentiality but OAuth also has other protections. Eg. against malicious JavaScript interceptong values like the authorization code. So TLS alone is insufficient.

Comment: How does it protect against JavaScript intercepting the tokens? The only way that can really be done is keeping it server side and cors.

Comment: So without TLS, PKCE still protects against stolen authorization codes being replayed at the token endpoint. Any real system also uses TLS. The trend these days is to use a backend for frontend also, if you are using a web client.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, but I don't understand how PKCE can be protected in a web browser without TLS. I understand that if a backend generates the HTML, it protects the calls to the API server from the front end, but it would still have the same issue if its connection was not protected with TLS. Ultimately, the tokens (no matter what the token is) are the key to the API, and whoever has it has access.

Comment: Of course you need TLS in any internet system, to ensure data confidentiality. Your question was whether PKCE as a mechanism works without TLS and it does, eg in a development system.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I appreciate your thoughts.